Is it possible to merge to Nexus T120 connections together?
A friend of mine recently was issued the 3M PELTOR™ ComTac™ V Headset for work.

They have a slick setup where you can connect each ear independently to a separate audio source so you can listen in to multiple things at the same time. The problem is for their upcoming job they only need to jack into a single audio source.
I'm guessing it has the same pinout as the ComTac II. If that's the case, is merging the two earphones together as simple as:

Figuring out which side has pin 3 or 4 active
Create a Y adapter which takes 3 from one and 4 from the other and merging them onto a single connector
Run the mic output from the active side (you can swap the mic to either side) to the mic output

I've built a couple of Arduino projects and it seems like this is fairly straightforward, but I'm not sure if there's something wonky my inexperience is causing me to miss.

Grant - I'm a moderator. Other list members closed the post. I considered reopening it as-is as it is excessively clear (to me) what you want to achieve. However, it would be helpful if you could address some of the points that Andy raised in meta,to whatever extent seems appropriate. That said, I'm not overly convinced that the question isn't OK as is. Then please flag the question and/or tag me here and I'll reopen it. . –

No problem! Will do when I get home. I’ll also fix the type-o in the title
